# Scraping Images that are Directly Embedded in a Webpage or Dynamic?

Tags: image, filtering, web-access

I need to scrape URLs for photo albums like Flickr and Facebook for images from a certain event.

I'm trying to use `Import["link", "Images"]`, as shown at

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ExtractImagesFromAWebpage.html

but as the website mentions, it's unable to pick up some images. Flickr and Facebook Photo Albums each use images that Mathematica is unable to pick up.

Is there a way I can get around this and import ALL images from a website onto Mathematica? I'm trying not to use the Flickr API.

Comment: Why not use the Flickr API? That’s exactly what APIs are for. The issue you’re running into is bag these resources are dynamically loaded via JavaScript (probably) and since they’re not in the raw HTML you can’t get them. On the other hand newer versions of Mathematica have support for web browser drivers you can work with that might get you there.

Comment: @b3m2a1 is referring to [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/WebDriverChrome.html).